# Ag-grid quickFilter cache first-time search

Tags: ag-grid

The quickFilter of Ag-grid with cacheQuickFilter enabled creates cache entries the first time the quickFilter is set. This causes a huge delay, but after that searching is pretty fast.

With 50k items in the grid, the page becomes unresponsive for a good 20 seconds. Is there a way to do this in a background web worker? Honestly I don't see the use of caching all entries if it means freezing the page for that long.

Comment: What is the searching like if you don't use `cacheQuickFilter`? The search [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) seems reasonably responsive with data size 50k rows (doesn't use `cacheQuickFilter`). If it works in the demo but not in your code: you might just have too much data (columns), or you might be doing something strange which we can't see because you haven't provided any code or a demo.

Comment: You're right, I found my mistake though. My valueGetter function was highly inefficient with a .find() lookup, I changed it to an object and now it's near instant.